# How to insert 1000 rows at a time

Tags: sql-server, database

I made Wpf appliaction. I want to test it with 1000 values in grid. I want to check that whether my grid will load 1000 data records fastly or not. So how to write one query to insert more than 1000 records in my database table. can i use for loop.

`Insert into db(@names,@email,@password) Values('abc','def','mypassword');`

*I am using Sql-Server 2012 and ADO.net Connectivity! I want to execute this query in database to generate 1000 rows*

**EDIT**

**What if i want to insert unique names?**

Comment: How are you generating these 1000 values? Are you using a DataTable to store your values? Have you looked in to [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)? Right now your question is overly broad because there are tons of ways of doing this depending on details you left out. Please explain more what technologies you are using (ADO.NET, Entitiy Framework, NHibernate) and how you are using it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes i am using database table named as `db`. I wan to write a query to generated 1000 rows in my table.

Comment: @Zoya he's asking where the 1000 names are coming from. Are you trying to generate 1000 names that are identical, 1000 names that are different (and if so, how)? Do you already have a list of 1000 names? Define your question better please.

Comment: When I need a once-off script to insert a bunch of test data, I'll often find a list of words (say a dictionary file), take as many words as I need and use multi-cursor editing in Sublime Text or similar to build up the SQL around them.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I create a `student` table with three column `id, student,age`. show you this example

```
declare @id int 
select @id = 1
while @id >=1 and @id <= 1000
begin
    insert into student values(@id, 'jack' + convert(varchar(5), @id), 12)
    select @id = @id + 1
end
```

this is the result about the example
[image]

Comment: What's the reasoning for having `@id >= 1` in the `while` clause? I'd think that only `@id <= 1000` would be necessary.

Comment: I deliberately downvoted this answer. In my opinion this post should not be tagged as 'answer'.(The answer of 'Aaron Bertrand' is the correct one.) Try this with 1 Million iterations and see how long you need for this loop. The problem is the log file is unnecessarily getting filled with every insert statement, which is slowing down the process and corrupting your log file.

Comment: Tried it with 1M rows, it took 19 seconds.... Admittedly my DB is running on 18 CPU cores, 150GB of RAM and full SSD, but still, this hardly seems slow. I wouldn't say it "corrupts" the log file, just writes to it normally.

Comment: where do you execute this code? as a stored procedure?

Answer (score 14):

**If you have a DataTable in your application, and this is where the 1000 names are coming from**, you can use a table-valued parameter for this.

First, a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Names AS TABLE
(
  Name NVARCHAR(255),
  email VARCHAR(320),
  [password] VARBINARY(32) -- surely you are not storing this as a string!?
);
```

Then a procedure to use this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Names_BulkInsert
  @Names dbo.Names READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.RealTable(Name, email, password)
    SELECT Name, email, password
    FROM @Names;
END
GO
```

Then your C# code can say:

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Names_BulkInsert", connection_object);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter names = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Names", DataTableName);
names.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**If you just want to generate 1000 rows with random values**:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT TOP (1000) n = REPLACE(LEFT(name,32),'_','')
  FROM sys.all_columns ORDER BY NEWID()
)
-- INSERT dbo.sometable(name, email, [password])
SELECT 
  name = LEFT(n,3),
  email = RIGHT(n,5) + '@' + LEFT(n,2) + '.com', 
  [password] = CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), SUBSTRING(n, 1, 32))  
FROM x;
```

**In neither of these cases should you be using while loops or cursors. IMHO.**

Answer (score 4):

You can of course use a loop, or you can insert them in a single statement, e.g.

```
Insert into db
(names,email,password) 
Values
('abc','def','mypassword')
,('ghi','jkl','mypassword2')
,('mno','pqr','mypassword3')
```

It really depends where you're getting your data from.

If you use a loop, wrapping it in a transaction will make it a bit faster.

**UPDATE**

> What if i want to insert unique names?

If you want to insert unique names, then you need to generate data with unique names.  One way to do this is to use Visual Studio [to generate test data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193262(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: "If you use a loop, wrapping it in a transaction will make it a bit faster." Reeeeeeallly? This is very interesting. I guess it makes sense. I'm going to go wrap one of my very slow loops in a BEGIN TRAN and see what happens.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald Yes really, but there is (a tradeoff.  If your transactions get huge, you can impact concurrency and even end up with a full transaction log.  So if you have a very large number of rows to insert, you should have a new transaction for every N rows, where the appropriate value for N will be specific to your environment.

Comment: Interesting. I ended up settling on a new transaction every 1,000 rows. My proc was taking an hour and now it's down to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert multiple records by inserting from a result:

```
insert into db (@names,@email,@password) 
select 'abc','def','mypassword' union all
select 'abc','def','mypassword' union all
select 'abc','def','mypassword' union all
select 'abc','def','mypassword' union all
select 'abc','def','mypassword' union all
select 'abc','def','mypassword'
```

Just add as many records you like. There may be limitations on the complexity of the query though, so it might not be possible to add as many as 1000 records at once.

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh: Yes, just put unique names in the select statements.

Comment: will they not repeat?

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh: Only if you run the query more than once. If you need to run it multiple times to get 1000 records, you need to change the names between each time to get unique names in the table.

Comment: So the suggestion here to generate 1000 unique names is to type out 1000 different names manually?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yes. If you want to generate unique names, that's a different question.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using a @Aaron Bertrand idea (`FROM sys.all_columns`), this is something that will create 1000 records :

```
 SELECT TOP (1000) LEFT(name,20) as names,
                   RIGHT(name,12) + '@' + LEFT(name,12) + '.com' as email, 
                   sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(HASHBYTES('MD5', name)) as password
 INTO db
 FROM sys.all_columns
```

See **[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9f72/1/0)**

Answer (score 2):

By the way why don't you use XML data insertion through Stored Procedure?

Here is the link to do that...
[Inserting Bulk Data through XML-Stored Procedure](http://www.programcall.com/11/dotnet/how-to-read-data-from-xml-string--and-insert-to-table-sql-server.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CTE as well. You can just modify it as you find fit. But this will add the same values into the student CTE.

This will add 1000 records but you can change it to 10000 or to a maximum of 32767

```
;WITH thetable(rowid,sname,semail,spassword) AS
(
    SELECT 1  , 'name' , 'email' , 'password'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rowid+1 ,'name' , 'email' , 'password' 
    FROM thetable WHERE rowid < 1000
)

SELECT rowid,sname,semail,spassword 
FROM thetable ORDER BY rowid
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @X INT = 1
WHILE @X <=1000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID, Age)
    VALUES(@X,LEFT(RAND()*100,2) 
    SET @X+=1
END;

    enter code here
DECLARE @X INT = 1
WHILE @X <=1000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID, Age)
    VALUES(@X,LEFT(RAND()*100,2) 
    SET @X+=1
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way.

Just stop execution in 10 sec.

```
Create table SQL_test  ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), UserName varchar(100)) 
while 1=1 
insert into SQL_test values ('TEST')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **GO** command for iterated above commands

```
INSERT INTO db(@names,@email,@password) 
VALUES('abc','def','mypassword')

GO 1000;
```

when you have identity column:
for example:

```
DROP TABLE student
CREATE TABLE student (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),FirstName varchar(10),PhoneNumber int)
```

---- after create table select this section and execute

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES( 'jack' + convert(VARCHAR(5), ISNULL(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),0)+1), 12)
GO 1000
```

Answer (score -1):

> if you're a beginner to sql like me us this

```
 create procedure insert1000record as
DECLARE @nbr INT=0
WHILE @nbr <1000
BEGIN
 insert into clients(client_ID) values(@nbr)
 SET @nbr = @nbr + 1
END
```

replace clients with your table name, and client_ID with your column_name
when you finish
execute the procedure with:

```
exec insert1000record
```

Comment: The same loop approach was posted 10 years ago - it has not improved with age.